# C++ typecast constant string within case

Tags: c++, string, casting, case

i would like to use already defined String characters of my program
within a switch case.

to clearify, my define looks like this

```
#define COMMAND "c"
```

in a different section i would like to uses this sign within a case statement.

```
switch ( sign )
{
  case COMMAND:
  break;
  ....
}
```

I know this is not allowed, but is there any way to typecast it to a char(it is only one char anyway)? The problem that i was facing is, that the compiler is then of cause complaining that
it is no constant any more...

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you define it as what you want? Like this

```
#define COMMAND 'c'
```

But wait... macros should be avoided as much as possible, haven't you heard this before? So don't do that either. Do this instead:

```
 constexpr char command = 'c';
```

Or if you have multiple commands, then maybe enum would be better:

```
 enum class command_type : char
 {
    command0 = 'c',
    command1 = 'd',
    command2 = 'e',
    //..
 };
```

Comment: of cause, but changing the define would result in a rat-tail of changes i would like to avoid.

Comment: That's worth doing it if that is possible.